# What kinds of laptop memory for Lenovo T400 laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am very ignorant about computer hardware. My Lenovo T400 laptop was purchased in 2009, and has only 2GB memory, and I hoped to increase its memory. (By the way, my OS is 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 )

1. Shall I purchase a larger laptop memory to replace my current one,
   or purchase another memory to be used together with my current one?
2. What information about my laptop are needed for choosing the
   compatible laptop memory? What memory size do you suggest?
3. How shall I open up my laptop, locate the current memory, and replace or add to  it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might as well go all the way to 8GB. It's cheap enough. You need two 4GB DDR3 sticks, DDR3-1333 or faster SDRAM SODIMMs. For Crucial, you can use part number CT2329970 (which is two sticks). You can use [this link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A8NX3CQ) to order from Amazon.

To upgrade the memory, remove the battery followed by the [palm rest](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-71480). It's held in by four screws in a row. You should see the [memory slots](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=MIGR-71483) in the middle. Remove the top stick first (if you have more than one). Insert the bottom stick first. Be sure it fully engages.

Comment: THanks! I think what you said might be right. I will order the one and see if it works out.

Comment: (1) The product on Amazon is 1333 MHz, while the official link for T400 recommend 1067MHz (also see karel's reply). Will 1333 MHz Ram be incompatible with T400? (2) What do you think about another product on NewEgg (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820144686), which is less expensive than the Amazon one?

Comment: (3) The bottom of my T400 says: "Product ID: 2764CTO;  Type-Model: 2764-CTO". So does it not belong to " T400 6473 6474 6475-xxx", which is in the product name in the Amazon link?

Comment: Hi David, I appreciate that you could help with my above questions.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing your RAM memory to the maximum supported amount of 4GB will give you much better performance in Ubuntu. Ubuntu's Unity desktop interface is similar to the Mac OS X desktop in look and feel, and it likes having a lot of memory. With the extra RAM memory, Firefox will give you better performance too.

---

- 3-8500 Non-Parity (NP) Double Data Rate Three (DDR3) Technology
- Two SO-DIMM Slots

  - The use of 1067 MHz SO DIMM memory is recommended for this system.
- 512 MB, 1 GB, 2GB, or 4GB memory
- Supports up to 4GB maximum memory

**Note:** Only 64-bit operating systems support more than 3GB of system memory (RAM).

<sup>**Source:** [Detailed specifications - Lenovo ThinkPad T400](https://support.lenovo.com/en_NO/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD005598)</sup>

Comment: [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/Lenovo-memory/ThinkPad+T+Series/ThinkPad+T400+Series-upgrades.html) says it can be upgraded to 8GB. Third parties often will do testing the manufacturer doesn't bother to do.

Comment: My Ubuntu is 32-bit 12.04. How much memory shall I buy? Or shall I install 64-bit Ubuntu? But I heard that many code don't run on 64-bit OS, and I am going to study for computer science master.

Comment: The default PAE kernel in later versions of Ubuntu 32-bit will support more than 3GB of RAM, but your operating system will run faster if you switch to Ubuntu 64-bit. If you upgrade to 4GB RAM you will notice an immediate increase in performance. Whatever you heard about code not running on 64-bit OS is a myth that has not been true for five years. You need a 64-bit OS to run virtual machines and SDKs efficiently. I would rather trust in the official Lenovo ThinkPad T400 website than believe in Crucial's marketing claims. You can break your laptop by installing incompatible hardware in it!

Comment: Will 32-bit OS working with a >= 4GB memory break your laptop?

Comment: 1.) Do you believe in Crucial more than Lenovo? Lenovo is the one who has to pay the warranty to fix your computer if something breaks, not Crucial. 2) The PAE kernel, which is the default kernel in recent Ubuntu releases, can use more than 3GB of RAM if you are running a 32-bit Ubuntu, so you could use a 32-bit Ubuntu after you have decided what you want do about my previous remark 1) of this comment.

Comment: @karel: Thanks! (1) Yes, I believe in Lenovo more. So is it correct that the hardware of T400 put a maximum restriction of 4GB on the RAM size, regardless of the OS? (2) Does 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 have PAE kernel. So is it correct that T400 with 32-bit Ubuntu can utilize up to 4GB RAM and no more than that? (3) Does T400 support 64-bit OS (Ubuntu or Windows)? (4) If I install 64-bit Ubuntu on T400, it will become even faster than 32-bit Ubuntu, but still can utilize up to 4GB RAM and no more than that?

Comment: (6) As a future programmer working in IT industry, will having a 64-bit Ubuntu be better than 32-bit Ubuntu? Similar for 64-bit Windows and 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Sorry for asking the above questions, and thanks in advance for helping again.

Comment: @T... You don't have to apologize for being interactive. Superuser is designed to be an interactive website. Also you've got enough reputation to continue any comment exchange in the [Superuser Root Access Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) or by moving it into another private Superuser chat room.

Comment: @karel: I don't see how I can move the conversation to a chat room. If you don't mind, could you answer my questions by adding some new comments, or editing your original post? Thanks!

Comment: @T... I have opened the following chat room: [Discussion between karel and T...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11979/discussion-between-karel-and-t). Ping me from the chat room and I will check in the chat room periodically and reply.